# Using a delegate target when binding for a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, plugins

I am writing a jQuery plugin.  When I am setting up the init method for this plugin, I want to set up events for the context, but am uncertain whether I should set a delegate target for the event or bind the event directly to the context.

My main reason for wanting to consider a delegate is the use of this plugin with dynamic content.  In certain cases, these elements that the plugin is called on may be appended to the page using ajax.  In this case, is there a way to set the events up so that I don't have to destroy and re-bind the events after ajax calls?

At the moment, I am doing something like this:

`$(this).on('click', initEditor);`

Should I consider doing something like this:

`$('body').on('click', this, initEditor);`

or event storing the delegate as an option in the options, like this:

`$(options.delegate).on('click', this, initEditor);`

I've noticed that, when using the delegate format, the event is bound to the context's selector, not the actual contextual element (i.e. if *this* is an anchor, it will bind to all anchors on the page).  Any way to avoid that?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying your plugin could be initialized on an element that does'nt exist ?

Comment: Generally, plugins don't target elements that don't exist yet, targeting dynamic elements is usually left to the developer using the plugin to avoid adding in unnecessary complexity to the plugin for those who don't need to use it on dynamic elements.

Comment: @alex23 - then you would'nt need a delegated event handler, as you would have access to the newly created elements inside the plugin anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to bind only on children elements you will use this:

```
$("#my_target").on("click", ".my_class_target", handler);
```

The ".on" event replaces "delegate, bind, live, etc". Now you can attach all events in only one place. This is very nice, because before that you need to use "bind" that didnt work with ajax elements, for that you have the "live" wich is limited.

In my example the attach you work only with ".my_class_target" that is inside the "#my_target". So if attach the start element on body like: "$("body").on("click", ".my_class_target", handle) so all ".my_class_target" will be attached. Then, the secret is in your "selector". 
Have in mind that the first selector "$(#my_target")" have to be created when the page is loaded and the other selector can be loaded by ajax or created by dom.

Lets take a example:

```
<div id="my_div">
    <ul class="ul-1">
        <li class="li-1-1"></li>
        <li class="li-1-2"></li>
        <li class="li-1-3"></li>
        <li class="li-1-4">
            <ul class="ul-2">
                <li class="li-2-1"></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

js:

```
my_function = function(){};
$("body").on("click", "li", my_function); //handle all li
$("body").on("click", "ul.ul-1 > li", my_function); //attach only in li-1-X 

// if ul-1 is generate with ajax:
$("#my_div").on("click", "li", my_function); // will work with all li
$("ul.ul-1").on("click", "li", my_function); // wont work because the first selector "ul.ul-1" was not generated when the attach was called.
```

I hope this help.

fonts:

http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I'm quite familiar with jQuery.on() and use it for all of my event bindings.  My question is more targeted towards whether it is good practice to use delegates for event bindings in plugins or to destroy and re-bind events when new DOM elements are attached to the DOM after the plugin has been called.

Comment: You can see [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L131) that jQuery add all events globally. So if you bind, destroy and rebind you will have more process than only do one bind. Because the selectors will be called in both cases, but only in the second the ":add" will be called. So I think the best way is do the attach in the onLoad and do all selectors you need. That is one of the reasons ".on" was created insted to use ".live".